# JsonRequestBehvior.AllowGet does not exist in the current context

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

I am using asp.net core to build an app and I am using jquery with controller.
When I make a post I want to send back as json but it is not defined as the photo
Any clue, what I miss in here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2155312.aspx?The+name+JsonRequestBehavior+doesnot+exist+in+the+current+context+Please+help). .Net Core does not define or need this Attribute, just remove it.